# Saving image, audio, and video to sd card

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-intent, android-camera

I am having trouble understanding how to save files to sdcard.  For my camera class I take a Picture, than create a new directory to save it in.  It creates the folder, but the image is not in the folder? please help.

```
if (items[which].equals("Picture")) {

                            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(
                                    MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent,
                                    PICTURE_ACTIVITY);

                            File imagesFolder = new File(Environment
                                    .getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                                    "SeccyPhotos");
                            imagesFolder.mkdirs(); // <----
                            File image = new File(imagesFolder, "image_001.jpg");
                            Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image);
                            cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                                    uriSavedImage);
                        }
```

I call the camera then after you take the picture it should save into folder.

Edit:
Would video be the same thing as camera?

```
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(
                                MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
                        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent,
                                PICTURE_ACTIVITY);

                        File videosFolder = new File(Environment
                                .getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                                "cangryVideos");
                        videosFolder.mkdirs(); // <----
                        File video = new File(videosFolder, "Video_001.3gp");
                        Uri uriSavedvideo = Uri.fromFile(video);
                        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                                uriSavedvideo);
                        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent,
                                PICTURE_ACTIVITY);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `startActivityForResult(cameraIntent,                                 PICTURE_ACTIVITY);` before setting the image file URI into `cameraIntent`.

Your code should be:

```
if (items[which].equals("Picture")) {
   Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

   File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
        "SecExPhotos");
   imagesFolder.mkdirs(); // <----
   File image = new File(imagesFolder, "image_001.jpg");
   Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image);
   cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,uriSavedImage);
   startActivityForResult(cameraIntent,PICTURE_ACTIVITY);
}
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: would video be a similar concept?

Comment: Have no idea. Haven't worked with video till now. I would suggest go ahead and try if you haven't already.